# How does GitHub know which user to associate with commits?

Tags: git, github

I have two GitHub accounts...one for work and one for personal projects.

After looking at commits on a personal project I've been working on I realized the committer for those commits was my work user.

I always authenticate over https and manually type in my (personal account's) credentials when working on this project.

The global `user.email` in my .gitconfig was pointing to my work email which I guess explains why those commits used my work profile.

So, as a test, I changed my `user.email` setting to my personal email address, made a test commit, and pushed to GitHub. *This commit is showing my personal GitHub user.*

**The only thing I changed was my `user.email` setting.**

It seems like I could have put any old email in there...would that then associate that commit with that random person?

I know it must not work like that, but **perhaps someone can explain more clearly how GitHub associates users with commits**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have a number of email addresses associated with your GitHub account in your GitHub profile (in your case seems like you have one email address per profile). When someone pushes a commit, GitHub looks at the commiter email address recorded in the commit header, looks up the GitHub account associated with this email, and that’s it.

For more details you might want to check this [GitHub help article](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user/).